# Icon does not changed on tapping in flutter custom widget

Tags: flutter

I have created a custom widget for list tile where I need to change icon of fav_outline to fav or google but it does not change, although items are adding and removing working properly but only icon does not change..it was working well before I created a custom widget for it

I have BottomNavigation for two screens alimonies and fav movies like that...

when I click on fav icon of all movie screen...it adds to fav movie ,,that's working fine, but only icon does not change

here is my coding of custom widget and my all movie screen..**both are stateful**

```
class MyCard extends StatefulWidget {

  final Movie e;
  final VoidCallback onfavtab;
  MyCard({required this.e,required this.onfavtab});
  
  @override
  State<MyCard> createState() => _MyCardState();
}

class _MyCardState extends State<MyCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(widget.e.name.toString()),
        subtitle: Text(widget.e.language),
        trailing: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: userlist[0].favmovies.contains(e)==true?Icon(Icons.favorite): Icon(Icons.favorite_outline),onPressed: widget.onfavtab),

            IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.delete)),
          ],
        ),
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(widget.e.imageurl),
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is my allmovie screen coding where I call custom widget

```
lass _AllMoviesState extends State<AllMovies> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      body: ListView(children: movielist.map((e) => MyCard(e: e, onfavtab: (){

          if(userlist[0].favmovies.contains(e)==true)
            userlist[0].favmovies.remove(e);
          else
            userlist[0].favmovies.add(e);

          //looks like this is not working
          setState(() {
            print(userlist[0].favmovies);
          });
        },
      )).toList(),),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put the icon which you need to edit it in provider class
and whene you click it just change the icon and notify it.